# Issue with vSphere ESXi 6.5 VM Autostart feature

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, vsphere, esxi

I am using ESXi 6.5 (ESXi build number: 5310538). 3 Months back I enabled Autostart and put 5 VMs in Autostart mode with default 120 sec start delay. Everything was working perfectly.

Last week, I disabled Autostart on 4 VMs and kept 1 VM as it is. Now in Autostart order column, 4 out of 5 VMs are showing Unset.

But even after disabling Autostart, when I reboot the ESXi host, all 5 VMs are getting Autostarted, which is not expected. It shows Autostart feature is not working well.

Could some please help me to understand where the exact problem is?

Comment: Are you able to post a screenshot of the config?

Comment: I have this same problem. I suspect it is a browser problem, are you using the web interface?